# 'if' without 'else' C#

Tags: c#

I am coding in C# 1.1.

I want a way to find out all the 'If' clause without the its 'else' clause. Is there any easy way?

I am asking this question because I got a project source file from my client which has many IF clause that doesnt have a ELSE clause. This is causing a lot of bugs. So, I want to scan my source file to see if there is any IF clause that doesn't have a ELSE clause.

thanks

Comment: Try rephrasing your question.  I'm not sure what exactly it is you are asking.

Comment: You mean you want to scan the source files which have an if condition without having an else condition?

Comment: Do you mean find all the areas in your code that have an if statement with no else? If so you can do that with a regular expression search from the find dialog.

Comment: Out of interest... why? (sickening pedant mode: it is C# 1.2, not 1.1)

Comment: Any particular reason to chose C# to write this code?

Comment: “This is causing a lot of bugs.”

– Somehow, I really doubt whether this is true.

Comment: There is no specific reason for choosing C#.

Comment: @pradeeptp - IMO, it is unlikely that the lack of an else block indicates a bug. Lack of **braces** might be more problematic. In either case, you'd have to look very hard to see if it is a problem or not. If I don't have alternative logic to write, I don't write an "else" block; that isn't a bug...

Comment: Great point Marc.  A lack of else clauses is not usually an error.

Comment: I agree with you Marc. The source code is not well written and due to poor handling of If conditions, I am seeing some algorithms wrongly executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll probably need to use a stack because an if could be inside another if.  Every time you find an if, push onto the stack.  Now look for the end of the phrase.  That means either a ; or matching curly braces.  After that, check for else.  Pop the stack.

Answer (score 4):

If no nifty tools are available:

1. Search for single word if in all files. To get a file with filename and line number.
2. Search for single word else in all files. To get a file with filename and line number.
3. In the first file, add "if" to each line, in the second add "else"
4. Merge files
5. Sort on filename, linenumber, (if/else)
6. Remove all ifs followed by an else.

You now have a list of almost all ifs without an else.

This method will give some false positives because it does not take commented code into account. But if no tools are available, it is a fair alternative.

Comment: Good idea. thanks. I want to see what others have to say about it.

Comment: This doesn't take into account nested if's.

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way for that.

Search **if** statements in project wide with **ctrl+shift+F**. 
And then quickly double-click the results.

Or maybe you can use **Find Options / Use / Regular Expressions** but I think it's not a good option.